# How to avoid HTML codes with Regular Expression

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I'm using google sheet and google webapp crud. for this i'm adding the HTML code into google sheets's cells to give better look into search results output.

The problem I'm facing is, when we do a search. e.g. I cannot filter the Mercedes Benz C Class because I have HTML code class= which is showing all results that contains C class. or Audi A4 etc...

To avoid extra spacing, I'm using this regular expression

```
var searchWords = searchinput.split(/\s+/);
```

E.g.I have the Google Sheet cell like this.

```
"<h6>MERCEDES BENZ C200 PREMIUM 2019</h6></b><p style='font-size:12px;color:#808080'>23003 KM</p> <div><a href='https://autodirect.lk/listings/mercedes-benz-c200-premium/'title='Website' target='_blank'><img src='https://img.icons8.com/plumpy/20/000000/technology-items.png'/></a>  
 <a href='https://docs.google.com/document/d/1l7sIdRPy2_t5_WavkyxoMpyaOMYi5mCBQCK0eQRk/preview'title='Quotation' target='_blank'><img src='https://img.icons8.com/plumpy/20/000000/paper--v1.png'/></a> <a href='https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mdASYRRd_bhngPVa0ZHFgDIFRPBOkr1Z'title='Images' target='_blank'><img src='https://img.icons8.com/plumpy/20/000000/camera.png'/></a></div>"
```

in the above code, I only want to have the below to be detected and avoid all other objects expect below words

The vehicle name and Year **MERCEDES BENZ C200 PREMIUM 2019**
**Image**
**Quotation**
**Website**

Is it possible to remove the HTML codes with regular expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is actually to use a library to do so. You can add a bundled library in a `.gs` file on Apps Script.

If for some reason you really want to do it yourself, you really need to know the possible outputs. Will it always 100% be the exact same format? If not, regex won't work.